# The meaning of ‘move to a human beat’ in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does ‘move to human beat’ mean to act according to what humans want?

> For many people, wildness is what we experience when we go into the
> woods, ascend a mountain, or explore a desert. Wildness, from this
> perspective, refers to the unwieldy character of the more-than-human
> world. In the woods, things happen on their own—in a manner that is
> indifferent and often resistant to human design. As the word’s
> etymology suggests, ‘wild’ things are self-willed. They operate
> according to their own unique dynamics. For Leopold and fellow
> conservationists, encountering things that refuse to **move** **to** **a** **human**
> **beat** is a rush; it enlivens life. For most others, however, it spells
> annoyance and peril.”(Excerpt From Is Wildness Over? By Paul Wapner)

Answer (score 2):

to move to a beat = to dance, basically, metaphor, live

**refuse** to move to a **human** beat = animals and insects and fish

Those organisms move to another beat.

There is a very old cliché in English: to march to **the beat of a different** drum.

A drum creates a beat; the sentence plays on that meaning.  Animal life marches to the beat of a drum that is not the one humans march to. A nice image.